OLS identity regressing $X_j$ on $X_{-j}$
Consider $X$ to be an $n \times p$ matrix, we select one column $X_k$ and consider the rest to be $X_{-k}$. Performing an OLS regression using $X_{-k}$ as the predictors for $X_k$, we get the residuals $R_k$ and coeff vector $\theta_k$.
Now consider the linear model $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ with the regular assumptions.
I was shown the following identity:
$\hat{\beta}^{OLS}_k = \frac{R_k^T Y}{R_k^TX_k}$ and have been trying to prove it. Where $\hat{\beta}^{OLS}$ is the OLS estimator for $Y$ on $X$, subscripting the kth entry.
I know that $R_k$ is going to be orthogonal to the column space of $X_{-k}$, so I can simplify it down there and get the identity $\beta_k = \frac{R_k^TX\beta}{R_k^TX_k}$, but I cannnot get the above.
As a second note I was told that $R_k^TX_k = ||R_k||^2$ which I cannot see.

I can't see how this is related to lasso.

@ZackFisher Apologies, I was studying this as an intermediary step to which I replace the OLS regressions to LASSO regressions, I have updated the title accordingly.

Let $$\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}}=X_{-k}(X_{-k}^TX_{-k})^{-}X_{-k}^T$$ be the projection matrix onto the column space of $X_{-k}$. Then $$R_k=(I-\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}})X_k.$$ It follows that
$$
\left\Vert R_k\right\Vert^2=R_k^TR_k=X_k^T(I-\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}})^2X_k=X_k^T(I-\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}})X_k = R_k^TX_k.$$
Since $\hat{\beta}_k$ can be obtained from regressing $(I-\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}})Y$ over $R_k$ (i.e., sequential decomposition of sums of squares), we have
$$\hat{\beta}_k = (R_k^TR_k)^{-1}R_k^T(I-\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}})Y=\frac{R_k^T(I-\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}})Y}{R_k^TR_k}
.$$
But $R_k^T(I-\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}}) = R_k^T$ since $R_k$ is already in the orthogonal complement of column space of $X_{-k}$. Also, shown above, $R_k^TR_k= R_k^TX_k$. The result immediately follows by plugging these two into the numerator and denominator of $\hat{\beta}_k$.

PS: some details to obtain $\hat{\beta}_k$:
With $$X=\begin{bmatrix}X_k & X_{-k} \end{bmatrix},$$ we have
$$\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY,
$$
where the Gram matrix is
$$X^TX =\begin{bmatrix} X_k^TX_k & X_k^TX_{-k} \\ X_{-k}^TX_k & X_{-k}^TX_{-k} \end{bmatrix}.
$$
By blockwise inversion (eqn 2 in the wiki link), the first row of $(X^TX)^{-1}$ can be shown as
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{R_k^TR_k} & -\frac{1}{R_k^TR_k}X_k^TX_{-k}(X_{-k}^TX_{-k})^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Multiply this by $X^TY=\begin{bmatrix}X_k^TY \\ X_{-k}^TY\end{bmatrix}$ to get
$$\begin{align}\hat{\beta}_k &= \frac{1}{R_k^TR_k}X_k^TY - \frac{1}{R_k^TR_k}X_k^TX_{-k}(X_{-k}^TX_{-k})^{-1}X_{-k}^TY \\
&=\frac1{R_k^TR_k}X_k^T\left(I-\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}} \right)Y \\
&=\frac1{R_k^TR_k}X_k^T\left(I-\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}} \right)^2Y \\
&=\frac{R_k^T \left(I-\mathcal{P}_{X_{-k}} \right)Y}{R_k^TR_k}
\end{align}$$

I follow the proof, although I do need to understand more explicitly why you can obtain $\hat{\beta}_k$ like that, drawing it out geometrically in 2D I can make sense of it. Thank you!

@Governor That's a basic result in linear model theory, usually introduced together with Cochran's theorem or type I sum of squares (for SAS users). Alternatively, you can directly verify that by $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$, where $X=\begin{bmatrix}X_k & X_{-k}\end{bmatrix}$.  Then you can find the first row of $(X^TX)^{-1}$ through [blockwise inversion] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion). It requires some messy calculations, but nothing is really special to get the result.

Odd I haven't seen it before in that guise, but it makes sense to me now, I ended up just brute forcing it to verify it using the Schur complement etc.

@Governor Just added a PS with some more details.
